# improperly structuring firebase get call unable to loop over returned data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase method that is executing inside of an Object.map:

// firebase call

```
  const getVisitors = (uid) => {
    let dbRef = ref(db, `organization/${org}/visitors/${uid}`);

    return get(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
      const visitor = snapshot.val();
      return visitor;
    })
  }
```

// where I execute method above:

```
    Object.keys(resultData.visitors[item]).map(async visitorEl => {
        const visitorObj = {};
        const individualVisitor = await getVisitors(visitorEl);
        console.log(individualVisitor);
        Object.keys(individualVisitor).forEach(el => {
          console.log(el);
        })
      })
```

I'm improperly structuring this for an asynchronous call but i'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  The first console.log logs the correct data which leads me to believe it's working properly

```
Object {
  "address": "5722 some street st",
  "bDay": "",
  "city": "Bsome city",
  "email": "",
  "first": "Richard",
  "gender": "M",
  "language": "Spanish",
  "last": "Gongaza",
  "mStatus": false,
  "phone": "323555",
  "profilePic": "",
  "visitDate": "2022-09-11-PM",
  "visitNote": "",
  "zip": "",
}
```

but the second console.log logs which tells me the data call hasn't resolved.

```
  _node
    ref
    _index
```

I await getVisitors.  Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this by breaking up the getVisitors method like so:

```
  const getVisitors = async (uid) => {
    let dbRef = ref(db, `organization/${org}/visitors/${uid}`);

    const snapshot = await get(dbRef);
    const value = snapshot.val();
    return value;
  }
```